# How to bundle cupy code to .exe by using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cupy

I'm trying to bundle a ".py" file which contains simple `cupy` code to ".exe" by `pyinstaller`, but fail to open the ".exe" file.

Target Code:

```
import cupy as cp

a = cp.ones(3)
b = cp.ones(3) * 7

print(a+b)
```

I tried to revise `hiddenimports` in ".spec" like:

```
 hiddenimports=[
    'C:\\Users\\Kevin\\miniconda3\\envs\\cupy_conda\\Lib\\site-packages\\cupy_backends\\cuda\\cuda\\cudnn.py',
    'cupy',
    'cupy_backends.cuda.api._runtime_enum',
    'cupy_backends.cuda.stream',
    'cupy_backends.cuda._softlink', #
    'cupy._core._carray',
    'fastrlock',
    'fastrlock.rlock',
    'cupy_backends.cuda.api._driver_enum',
    'cupy._core._ufuncs',
    'cupy._core._cub_reduction',
    'cupy._core._routines_sorting',
    'flags'
    ],
```

and bundle again.

`(cupy_conda) PS C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\plot> pyinstaller main.spec`

Use cmd to execute the ".exe" file .

However, cmd output `pyinstaller importerror: cannot import name flags` again.

[image]

Do I use the wrong way to bundle `cupy` code?
Or how to fix it?